# Set Html.ActionLink's  Visibility, Best approach ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visibility, actionlink

I have boolean value in my model and I return this model to view. I want to control actionlink visibility with this value. I found two example like this:

First

```
@if (Model.UserCanCreate)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
}
```

Second

```
<li style="visibility: @Model.UserCanCreate">@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</li>
```

What is the best way to show/hide htmlHelpers?

Thanks.

Comment: @DanielB: you mean the *first*, right? The 2nd writes the link to the page and just hides it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option is the correct one.

```
@if (Model.UserCanCreate)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
}
```

Never rely on visibility in the browser, give the the user only what he is allowed to see.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is better for your case. 
If you use second - there will be hidden link on the page to do something, but in first case there will not any info about possibility to do ("Create New", "Create").